# integration question A

Tags: integration

I really don't know how to integrate this.

$$\int \frac{dx}{(1-x)(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

I tried to expand the brackets $$(1-x)(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ and then I don't know how to carry on...

Comment: Tommy, is the following what you intend? $\int \frac{dx}{(1-x)(1-x^2)^{1/2}}$

Comment: yes, it is. Sorry that i couldn't type it.

Answer (score 2):

As Bubububu said, substitute $x$ with $\sin(t)$

$$\int\frac 1{1-\sin(t)}dt$$

Multiply numerator and denominator with $1+\sin(t)$.

$$\int\frac {1+\sin(t)}{\cos^2(t)}dt$$

$$\int(\frac {1}{\cos^2(t)} + \frac{\sin(t)}{\cos^2(t)}) dt$$

$$\int(\sec^2(t) + \sec(t)* \tan(t) ) dt$$

$$ \tan(t) + \sec(t) + c$$

Answer (score 0):

You can try to substitute $sint=x$ directly. Your integral will become

$$\int\frac 1{1-sint}dt$$

Then try to simplify the denominator.

Comment: how do you know we need to use sint = x?? How can I spot this?

Comment: @tommypalji usually when we see $\frac{1}{\sqrt1-x^2}}$ , we will try using $x=sint$ because $\sqrt{1-sin^2t}=cost$, which will be cancelled by $dx=costdt$.